# Python, using real byte values in Bytearray

Tags: sockets

I'm using Socket-Communication between my PC and a SPS Unit. They are charing bytes to communicate, by using the python bytestring().
On PC side, I have to switch numeric commands (integer), but them into the bytestring and send it via socket.
Values from 8, 9, 12 and much more, produces an error on SPS side, because the are changed by UTF-8: 8 --> \t , 9 --> \n.
How can I keep this data in real hex and without coding UTF?

```
my_b = bytearray()
my_b.append(8) #fill with Bytevalues
my_b.append(9)
my_b.append(10)
my_b.append(11)
my_b.append(12)
my_b.append(13)
print (my_b)
>> bytearray(b'\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not being changed. `\t`, `\n` and `\r` are simply built-in short-hand for expressing the byte values of 9, 10, and 13. Those values are ASCII control characters (tab, line-feed and carriage-return, specifically).

To prove this, add these lines to the end of your code snippet:

```
with open("/tmp/foo", "wb") as f:
    f.write(my_b)
```

Then dump `/tmp/foo` as hex bytes:

```
od -tx1 /tmp/foo
0000000 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d
0000006
```